# Connectivity issues with EC2 Windows server through NAT server

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nat

I am having difficulties understanding why my EC2 Windows machine is refusing to connect to the internet through NAT server.

All of my VPC output connections are redirected through a NAT server.
On the same subnet and security group I have a linux machine that is able to connect to the internet (on port 80 and 443). But the windows server machine cannot.

Note that if i put the windows machine in a public subnet and allow all outbound traffic, everything works and i can browse.

Is there something I am missing in the windows configuration, I am really weak with administrating windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you AWS Settings are Right (SG,NW-ACL,etc) and Still you are not able to connected to Internet from Windows Server.

I think You have not allowed the Windows Firewall to allow traffic , Turning it off is not recommended.

Try to Create a Rule in Firewall that will allow you to Bypass the Port in the Windows Firewall.

Refer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753558.aspx

Comment: I turned it off for sanity and it didn't work. Another indication that the firewall is not the issue is that when i open all traffic outbound (or just 80,443) I can browse just fine.